# JavaScript Promises - Waiting for resolution before moving on

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise, bluebird

I have a requirement to do the following:

1. Get a list of "lines" by calling an internal function (getLines()).
2. Select the first line, perform an action
3. After the previous action finishes, select the next line and do the same action
4. Repeat for all lines (3-20 depending on user)

I have the following code in place:

```
App.Lines = response.data;    
for (var _i = 0; _i < App.Lines.length; _i++) {
    var makeCallPromise = new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            Session.connection.ol.makeCall(App.Lines[_i], callBackFunction(response) {
                //this can take up to 30 seconds to respond...
                resolve(response.data);
            }, errorCallBackFunction(message) {
                reject(message.error);
            }, bareJid);
        }
    )
    makeCallPromise.then(function(fulfilled) {
        console.log("PROMISE WORKED!!!!!", fulfilled);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("PROMISE FAILED!!!!!", error);
    });
}
```

My hope was that the loop would wait to resolve the promise before it continued the loop, however, that's not the case.
My question is whether or not it's possible to halt the loop until the resolution is complete.
Note - I am using the bluebird JS library for promises.
Thank you!

Kind Regards,

Gary

Comment: I think that you have to `return` the promise in some way. Like in this case `fulfilled` is the key phrase that you use in your promise.

Comment: Instead of looping the entire thing, loop makeCallPromise and push those promises to an array. Then use Promise.all( array ) and add the `then()` calls after the promise.all. The result will be that all promsies willl resolve before the first `then()` is called, so all data is available to loop over again. Alternatively, don't use a loop at all, but make the next makeCallPromise after the former resolves.

Comment: @Shilly Thanks, I've tried using this in the answer provided by marvel308, with Promise.each(). My response is there on what I did and what happened.

Comment: Promises 101 - promises don't make asynchronous code synchronous :p

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about bluebird, but you can do something like that to create some kind of for loop that waits for each promise to end before the next iteration.

Here is a generic example, it could certainly be optimized, it's just a quick attempt:

```
var i = 0;
var performAsyncOperation = function(operationNumber) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log('Operation number', operationNumber);
    resolve();
  });
}

var chainAsyncOperations = function() {
    if(++i < 10) {
        return performAsyncOperation(i).then(chainAsyncOperations);
    }
};
performAsyncOperation(i).then(chainAsyncOperations);
```

Hoping this will help you ;)

Comment: clean working solution without 3rd party libs. this is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promise.each()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) provided by bluebird, It would traverse an array serially and wait for them to resolve before moving to the next element in the array

Comment: I've tried using by iterating over the promises and creating an array of them (rather than resolving them in the iteration). I've then called 'Promise.each(promiseArray, function(result){console.log(result)}.then(function(fulfilled){console.log("WORKED")}).catch(function(error){console.log("ERROR")}));'. The problem is that this doesn't work, it still tries doing both Session.connection.ol.makeCall without waiting for the first to resolve.

Comment: Did you use bluebird ?

Comment: Hmm I've loaded the bluebird library by including it in <script>, but I'm not using node.js so I've not done the npm install or the require. Sounds like this is required?

Comment: Ignore last comment, I'm loading it correctly using requirejs: `requirejs(['bluebird'], function (Promise) {//application code here});`. This is still not working though, it's calling both makeCall functions without waiting.

Answer (score 0):

This Use Case perfectly matches the ES7 feature `async await`, If you have the possibility to transpile your code using babeljs, you could refactor your function like this :

```
function createPromise(line) {
    return new Promise(
       function(resolve, reject) {
          Session.connection.ol.makeCall(line, callBackFunction(response) {
              //this can take up to 30 seconds to respond...
              resolve(response.data);
          }, errorCallBackFunction(message) {
              reject(message.error);
          }, bareJid);
       }
    );
}

App.Lines = response.data;

async function main() {
    for (var _i = 0; _i < App.Lines.length; _i++) {
        try {
           var result = await createPromise(App.Lines[_i]);
           console.log(result);
        } catch (err) {
           console.log(err);
        }
    }
}

main().then(function() {
    console.log('finished');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Bluebird#each` method:

> .each(function(any item, int index, int length) iterator) -> Promise
>
> Iterate over an array, or a promise of an array, which contains promises (or a mix of promises and values) with the given iterator function with the signature (value, index, length) where value is the resolved value of a respective promise in the input array. Iteration happens serially. If any promise in the input array is rejected the returned promise is rejected as well.

```
Promise.each(App.Lines, line => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Session.connection.ol.makeCall(line, callBackFunction(response) {
            resolve(response.data);
        }, errorCallBackFunction(message) {
            reject(message.error);
        }, bareJid);
    })
    .then(fulfilled => console.log("PROMISE WORKED!!!!!", fulfilled))
    .catch(err => onsole.log("PROMISE FAILED!!!!!", err));
});
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't working, I don't really understand what it's doing. In a simple case of 1 Line value, it looks like it's issuing `Session.connection.ol.makeCall` twice in the same moment, so we instantly get a failure. When I update this to 2 Lines, it issues 4 `Session.connection.ol.makeCall` in a moment, then later on it issues 2 more after the response comes back.

Comment: According the code in your question, `App.Lines` is an array of lines, in my code I use `Bluebird#each` method to iterate over that array and call `Session.connection.ol.makeCal` for each line. Are you sure that `App.Lines` has one line (one element) in first case and two lines in the second? Add `console.log(App.Lines.length)` before `Promise.each`.